# how to turn this function to be recursive with multiple dimensional array?

Tags: php, function, recursion, multidimensional-array

Hello I am think about how to build this array with a recursive function with a lot of layer.
So the data would like that.

```
id belongs_to
1a  NULL
2a  NULL
3a  1a
4a  NULL
5a  2a
```

And non-recursive function like:

```
foreach ($first_layer as $first_layer_obj) {
        $array[$first_layer_obj->id] = [];
        $second_layer = /* SELECT id FROM client WHERE belongs_to $first_layer_obj->id */;
        foreach ($second_layer as $second_layer_obj) {
            $array[$first_layer_obj->id][$second_layer_obj->id] = [];
            $third_layer = /* SELECT id FROM client WHERE belongs_to $second_layer_obj->id */;
            foreach ($third_layer as $third_layer_obj->id) {
                $array[$first_layer_obj->id][$second_layer_obj->id][$third_layer_obj->id] = [];
            }
        }
```

I am expecting the output is:

```
array(3) {
["1a"]=>
   array(1){
     ["3a"]=>[]
   }
["2a"]=>
   array(1){
     ["5a"]=>[]
   }
["4a"]=>[]
}
```

Comment: What should happen if 2a belongs to 3a and 3a belongs to 2a?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build a tree from a flat array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840319/build-a-tree-from-a-flat-array-in-php)

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the first item is the top item and any below will be children? Meaning the further down you go the array the lower level it is?

Comment: @Leaben This is close but not exactly you preferred format: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47846237/2943403

Answer (score 0):

Certainly the first piece of advice that I have is, you should avoid performing recursive/iterated calls to your database.  You should make a single call to extract all of the desired rows in a single result set and let php do the hard part.

I've decided to try a non-recursive approach.  To permit this, the result set must be prepared so that "grander" children are listed first.  Now, I realize that it is entirely possible that your sample data doesn't actually represent your project values and sorting cannot be used to prepare the result set adequately -- you'll have to let me know (and perhaps update your question with more accurate sample data).

[see inline comments for what's happening in my script]

*If you aren't using php7+, then my null coalescing operator (`$row1['children'] ?? []`) will cause issues.
  You can use: `(isset($row1['children']) ? $row1['children'] : []`

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/97S5I))

```
// use ORDER BY belongs_to DESC, id ASC ... or usort() to prepare result set
$resultset = [
    ['id' => '6a', 'belongs_to' => '5a'],
    ['id' => '5a', 'belongs_to' => '3a'],
    ['id' => '8a', 'belongs_to' => '3a'],
    ['id' => '3a', 'belongs_to' => '1a'],
    ['id' => '1a', 'belongs_to' => null],
    ['id' => '2a', 'belongs_to' => null],
    ['id' => '4a', 'belongs_to' => null],
    ['id' => '7a', 'belongs_to' => null]
];

foreach ($resultset as $index1 => &$row1) {             // make input array modifiable by reference (not working with a copy)
    if ($row1['belongs_to']) {                          // original belongs_to value is not null (not a top-level parent)
        foreach ($resultset as $index2 => $row2) {      // search for targeted parent
            if ($row2['id'] == $row1['belongs_to']) {   // parent found
                $resultset[$index2]['children'][] = [$row1['id'] => $row1['children'] ?? []];  // store original row as child
                unset($resultset[$index1]);             // remove original row (no reason to iterate it again in outer loop)
                break;                                  // halt inner loop (no reason to iterate further)
            }
        }
    } else {                                            // original belongs_to value is null (top-level parent)
        $output[$row1['id']] = $row1['children'] ?? [];  // store children to top
    }
}
var_export($output);
```

Output:

```
array (
  '1a' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      '3a' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          '5a' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              '6a' => 
              array (
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          '8a' => 
          array (
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  '2a' => 
  array (
  ),
  '4a' => 
  array (
  ),
  '7a' => 
  array (
  ),
)
```

Comment: @Leaben Have I solved your question to your satisfaction?